# What is a "sequence of arbitrary events"?

Tags: probability, notation

In my lecture notes for the probability course I am taking the word "arbitrary" appears a lot to refer to sequences of events. But I'm not sure what exactly this means. In a supplementary section, I have a lemma which reads:

"Let $(A_a)_{a \in \mathcal{A}}$ and $(B_b)_{b \in \mathcal{B}}$ be arbitrary, countable or uncountable, collections of sets..."

Which leads me to think that arbitrary means countable or uncountable. But in the first chapter I have an example saying:

"If $(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of arbitrary events in some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$, then the sequence $(B_n)_{n \geq 1}$ with $B_n = \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$ is increasing."

The index of the union at the end suggest to me that the $A_k$ must be countable in this case, otherwise I don't see how this makes sense. So what exactly does arbitrary mean?

Comment: it just means you make no other assumptions (e.g you’re not assuming something speciifc like $A_1$ has 7 elements and $A_n$ has $11$ elements and that $A_3,A_4,\dots$ etc are empty, or some other weird ‘specific’ stuff). Does *“Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ be sets of indices and $(A_{a})_{a\in\mathcal{A}},(B_b)_{b\in\mathcal{B}}$ be collections of sets”* sound better/cause less confusion?

Comment: Wherea *$(A_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is a sequence of arbitrary events in some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$* means $A_n$ is an (of course countable) sequence of "arbitrary" sets with the additional condition that $A_n\in\mathcal F$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo If $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ were sets of indices, would that not imply that $(A_a)_{a \in \mathcal{A}}$ and $(B_b)_{b \in \mathcal{B}}$ are countable?

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you both. So the "arbitrary" is in reference to each $A_a$ themselves, i.e. it is a statement about the set, not the sequence.

Comment: The sets of indices are not necessarily countable. $(A_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\mathcal A}$ is an [indexed family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_family). If you prefer, it's a function from $\mathcal A$ to $\mathcal F$. However, the *sequence* $(A_n)_{n\ge1}$ is a *countable* indexed family.